# C# Save only one item in Application settings

Tags: c#, application-settings

When you use:

`Properties.Settings.Default.Save();`

It saves all settings. Is it possible to somehow only save one specific setting ?

Comment: But why would you modify some settings if you don't want all of them be saved?

Comment: My application has two logically independent groups of settings, each with its own settings window. If the user accepts their changes to one group of settings, I don't want it to also save the other group.

Answer (score 0):

Just change one property and at a time and call Save after it

```
Properties.Settings.Default.MyProperty = "ABC";
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```